# Getting Spring object instantiation right

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

I'm new to Spring and a little confused about how it works. I get that I can use the application context to instantiate beans and have them populated. However, is the idea that I should be able to just write `Bean b = new Bean()` and then have Spring to somehow automagically populate that Bean?

I'm experimenting with Spring in a web application, and as far as I can see I need to inject the `ApplicationContext` into, say, the servlets to be able to instantiate other beans (services, daos etc.) from there. It's a bit cumbersome, but probably works.

However, is Spring meant to be able to hook into any object instantiation which happens on classes defined as beans in applicationContext.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Spring is an Inversion of Control container. A bean is an object whose life cycle is managed by Spring. If you want Spring to populate an object, it needs to go through Spring, ie. it needs to be bean.

> is Spring meant to be able to hook into any object instantiation
>   which happens on classes defined as beans in applicationContext.xml?

Spring doesn't hook into anything. You configure your beans and the relationships between them with Spring and Spring handles creating the instances and linking them up.

Answer (score 0):

For domain objects, Spring provides a solution via the `@Configurable` annotation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-atconfigurable

It requires compile- or load-time-weaving and, thus, introduces some additional complexity but having the convenience of using the standard `new Bean()` syntax plus Spring's autowiring is worth it in my opinion.

Alternatively, you could define your domain objects as beans with `prototype` scope and use some factory to create them using the Spring `ApplicationContext.getBean()` method. With a scope of `prototype` a new instance will be returned every time and since you go through the ApplicationContext, Spring will do all the dependency injection magic as usual.

As for services and other beans with `singleton` scope, you would typically NOT retrieve them by first injecting the `ApplicationContext` and using it but instead you would inject them via either a constructor, setter or annotation-based strategy. The documentation covers that in detail: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-collaborators